# Show that this map is a submersion.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ an open set and consider $f\in C^{\infty}(U,\mathbb{R})$ i need to show that the map
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
F \ : & \! U\times (\mathbb{R}^n)^* & \! \longrightarrow
& \! \mathbb{R} \\
& \! (x,A) & \! \longmapsto
& \! f(x)+Ax
\end{array}
$$

it's a submersion. Well I tried calculate $D_1F_{(x,A)}=df(x)+A$, so when $A=-df(x)$ this is are zero, it's true this question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to show that the total derivative $DF(x,A):\Bbb R^n \times (\Bbb R^n)^*\to \Bbb R$ is surjective. So pretend that $x$ and $A$ depend on a parameter $t$ and take the derivative with respect to $t$ to get $$DF(x,A)(\dot{x},\dot{A}) = Df(x)(\dot{x}) + \dot{A}x + A\dot{x}.$$Now, freeze $x$ and $A$, take $c \in \Bbb R$, and ask yourself: is it possible to solve $$Df(x)(\dot{x}) + \dot{A}x + A\dot{x}=c$$for $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{A}$? If $f = 0$ and $(x,A) =(0,0)$ it is impossible, as $DF(x,A)$ is the zero map. This shows that in general you need more assumptions. Rewrite the equation as $$(Df(x)+A)\dot{x} + \dot{A}x=c.$$If $x\neq 0$, then you can define a linear map $\dot{A}:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ by $\dot{A}x=c$ and $\dot{A}|_{x^\perp}=0$, so that $DF(x,A)(0,\dot{A})=c$, as wanted. We conclude that if $0\not\in U$, then $F$ is a submersion.